# Bootstrap 3 Tablet Portrait size makes columns overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a calendar that uses the `bootstrap` grid system. Currently I am using `col-sm-9` for the right columns, and `col-sm-3` for the left. This works great, until I size down to what I think tablet portrait would be (right before it breaks to the phone layout).

When this happens, the right column overlaps the left, and I cannot figure out why.

[image]

Link to calendar: http://www.puc.edu/dev-calendar

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this? Should I instead add some larger breakpoints and adjust the `col-sm-*` to something like 4 and 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. The only changes you need:

1. Change `row` to `row-fluid` so you will have `row-fluid calendar-loading-area` on the immediate `div` in `container`
2. Change immediate children of `calendar-loading-area` to `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` from `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9` respectively.

The key here is to have `row-fluid` instead of `row`.

Comment: Perfect! That worked! I also added `col-md-9` and `col-md-3` to make it look right at larger sizes. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the `row-fluid` class has been removed since Bootstrap v3

Answer (score 0):

Change the `events.events-week` col's to:

```
col-sm-8 col-sm-push-1
```

See [responsive column offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) & [offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).